# System of Linear Inequalities to create feasible solution $y=\min(x_1,x_2)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have a question in optimization. The question is $L_{1}\leq x_{1}\leq U_{1}$,..., $L_{n}\leq x_{n}\leq U_{n}$. Can we introduce decision variables and define a system of mixed-integer linear inequalities whose feasible solution is $y=\min(x_{1},...,x_{n})$?

Additional requirement for the question is include the fewest possible number of constraints and decision variables.

Thank you.

Comment: Does adding an auxiliary variable $x_3$ to minimise in your objective, with the added constraints $x_3\ge x_1, \, x_3\ge x_2$ take care of it?

Comment: @Macavity. I feel like this is a good starting point. But not sure if I am allowed to add a max/min target function here. Also you can see I just edited the question which is expanded to N case and needs fewest possible number of constraints (I feel like this is where an integer variable comes in but still thinking how)

Comment: Why don’t you quote the exact question rather than keep modifying it? As it is, it is not at all clear. If it’s an optimisation problem, there must be an objective to it. And what are $x_i$ if they are not decision variables? What is $y$ and what do you mean by feasible solution?

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the full problem clearly here at first. I think the problem is on reformulate constraints that we already have $l_{i}<=x_{i}<=u_{i}$ and y = min($x_{1}$,...$x_{n}$). The question is how to reformulate y=min($x_{1}$,...,$x_{n}$) with mixed-integer inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that there are other constraints on the $x$ variables that are not listed; otherwise, just add the constraints $x_i=L_i$ and $y=\min_i L_i$. With that assumption in place, you could add binary variables $z_1,\dots, z_n$, along with constraints $y_i \le x_i \,\forall i$, $y_i \ge x_i - U_i (1-z_i)\,\forall i$, and $\sum_i z_i = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Based on my current understanding of the problem, it is on reformulate constraints. We already have $l_{i}<=x_{i}<=u_{i}$,i=1,...,n and y = min($x_{1}$,...$x_{n}$). Then how to reformulate y=min($x_{1}$,...,$x_{n}$) with a system of mixed-integer inequalities.

Comment: I see your post at https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/01/max-and-min-functions-in-mip.html. I think my question is same as the one in your post except change maximization to minimization.